# How can I copy a subtree from one TTreeView to another?

Tags: delphi, loops, treeview, iteration

I want to copy the selected node and all its descendants from one TTreeView to another.

What is the best, most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't get the whole idea of what you are trying to do... if you want only the child nodes of the selected one, no one can be the parent of it, or the grand-parent of itself!... re-think the way you're expressing what you need and reword your post!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's easiest to do this recursively, something like this:

```
procedure WalkChildren(Node: TTreeNode; List: TList<TTreeNode>);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  List.Add(Node);
  for i := 0 to Node.Count-1 do begin
    WalkChildren(Node[i], List);
  end;
end;
```

Call it like this:

```
List := TList<TTreeNode>.Create;
WalkChildren(Root, List);
```

This example adds to a list but you can replace that action with one of your choosing.

Now that we can walk one tree, it's time to walk two trees in tandem.

```
procedure CopySubTree(Src, DestParent: TTreeNode; DestNodes: TTreeNodes);
var
  i: Integer;
  Dest: TTreeNode;
begin
  Dest := DestNodes.AddChild(DestParent, Src.Text);
  //copy other parameters from Src to Dest as you please
  for i := 0 to Src.Count-1 do begin
    CopySubTree(Src[i], Dest, DestNodes);
  end;
end;
```

You can call it like so:

```
CopySubTree(SrcTree.Selected, nil, DestTree.Items);
```

Comment: Aww man - I could have answered this one, and I rarely can! :P

Comment: Sorry David, perhaps my question was not so clear. I have attached a screenshot to show exactly what I am looking for.Also in your code I had to change Node.Items[i] to Node[i], though if my question was misunderstood that procedure will no longer be needed.

Comment: @Craig give me 10 minutes and I'll add code for walking both trees in tandem

Comment: @David the time is running. ;)

Comment: @RRUZ Yes, I got side-tracked.

Comment: @Craig I've updated the answer. I've not run this code, but I'm quietly confident that it will work! Thanks a lot for a very interesting and challenging question.

Comment: It works perfect thanks David, I have accepted your answer. Sorry for the initial mix up, though your first piece of code will provide useful in other situations

Comment: Doh! I spent too much time writing my answer and ended up duplicating yours.

Comment: @Rob The name of your function is better than mine. I've copied it. Thanks! Your comments and the assertion are valuable. If you don't want to undelete your answer then I'll probably copy those too. On the other hand there's something to be said for having one very terse answer, and one more explanatory version. I've voted to undelete your answer and would up-vote it if I could!

Comment: @David: +1 for the turn of phrase "walk two in tandem" alone. ;) Seriously, nice answer.

Comment: @David, I edited your CopySubTree procedure to include the ability to pass the Image Indexes from the source node, to the destination node.